# Create Sector PRACH in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I am trying to write a code that creates the PRACH per sector per band for a site.

My PRACH data contains: "Site name, lat, long, beamwidth, azimuth, and distance"

I got to the point of creating points, but I can't somehow create the Pie-shaped sector that is represented with the variables that my data contains.

Also, if it were to be created, how can I make it loop till it creates 5000 sectors for instance?

You can find an example in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  After receiving an answer to this question you have asked [another](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136663/same-sector-created-in-mapinfo-help) which seems closely related.  I think you should probably Accept the answer to this question, and then reference this Q&A in the later question to help explain what you have done and where you are now stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at these threads:

- [Creating an annulus sector with MapBasic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121582/creating-an-annulus-sector-with-mapbasic/121748#121748)
- [Drawing BTS Sectors in GSM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131075/drawing-bts-sectors-in-gsm)

For the looping I expect that you have your data in a table that you can loop over. If so you can use this structure for the looping:

```
Fetch First From PRACH_TABLE
Do Until EOT(PRACH_TABLE)
   '**Do the work here

   Fetch Next From PRACH_TABLE
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks! will try it out and will let you know how it works out.
Truly appreciate it Peter!