# Same Sector Created in Mapinfo Help

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, loop

The PRACH data is saved into a tab and then moved into another tab file "ToUpdate"

```
Select * from PRACH_data where Obj into ToUpdate

Fetch First From ToUpdate
Do While Not EOT(ToUpdate)
circ = CreateCircle(Longitude, Latitude, r)
Fetch Next From ToUpdate
Loop

Fetch First From ToUpdate
Do While Not EOT(ToUpdate)
azimuth = ToUpdate.Azimuth
BW = ToUpdate.HBW
s = azimuth -(BW/2)
e = azimuth + (BW/2)
Create Arc into Variable pie (ObjectGeography(circ, 1), ObjectGeography(circ, 2)) (ObjectGeography(circ, 3), ObjectGeography(circ, 4)) s e
pie=converttopline(pie) 
Fetch Next From ToUpdate
Loop

Fetch First From ToUpdate
Do While Not EOT(ToUpdate)
alter Object pie Node Add (Longitude, Latitude)
pie=converttoregion(pie)
Insert into WindowInfo(FrontWindow(),10) (obj) Values (pie)
Fetch Next From ToUpdate
Loop

Commit Table ToUpdate Interactive
```

The thing is, the program isn't going to the NEXT row/cell in the excel file and creating a new pie at that sector... I am getting 5000 pies (same shape, same Lat, same Lot, same Beamwidth, same azimuth) but not on different points like I want..

It can be viewed in the following pic.
[image]

Can someone help please?

Comment: Rather than post this as a new question, please edit your original question to include what you have done.

Comment: I can understand the sentiment of the above comment by @Fezter.  For this question not to be made a duplicate of the earlier one it may be worth using the **edit** button beneath each to tease the content of the two questions apart so that each becomes/stays answerable in its own right.  It is often hard to draw the line between one question and the next (which may follow on from it) but is nevertheless a valuable problem-solving skill to have.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have three loops but you don't store the individual results from the first two loops and so the third loop will only work on the last result.

Try to modify your program to only have one loop like this:

```
Fetch First From ToUpdate
Do While Not EOT(ToUpdate)
   circ = CreateCircle(Longitude, Latitude, r)

   azimuth = ToUpdate.Azimuth
   BW = ToUpdate.HBW
   s = azimuth -(BW/2)
   e = azimuth + (BW/2)
   Create Arc into Variable pie 
      (ObjectGeography(circ, 1), ObjectGeography(circ, 2)) 
      (ObjectGeography(circ, 3), ObjectGeography(circ, 4)) 
      s e
   pie=converttopline(pie) 

   alter Object pie Node Add (Longitude, Latitude)
   pie=converttoregion(pie)

   Insert into WindowInfo(FrontWindow(),10) (obj) Values (pie)

   Fetch Next From ToUpdate
Loop
```

And if you are reading your longitude, latitude and radius values from the table you need to change the statement to reflect that:

```
   circ = CreateCircle(ToUpdate.Longitude, ToUpdate.Latitude, ToUpdate.r)
```

Comment: Peter that worked in one loop and updating the long, lat with the new table as well.

Comment: @Karl Please take the [Tour] to learn about the Accept button.