# Sectors pointing to a lat long

Tags: mapinfo, latitude-longitude, mapbasic, geolocation

Is it possible to find which sectors of a site are pointing to a specific lat long at a distance away?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a programmed solution for you, but here are some considerations:

**Limit the dataset**

Find the sectors that are within a certain distance to limit your dataset to search

**Find the sectors that point to the point**

Now you need to figure out if the sectors are pointing in the direction of the point you are at. I an see at least two ways:

2a. Calculate the bearing from the sector to the point and see if that bearing lies within the coverage bearing of the sector.

2b. For all sectors you can create a polyline x meters out covering the bearing this sector points towards. 
Have a look at this answer which might be helpful: [Creating an Annulus Sector with MapBasic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121582/creating-an-annulus-sector-with-mapbasic)

Now you can draw a line between the sectors found in 1. and the point. With a Select you can find all the polylines that are crossed by the line from the point to the sector. Remember to also include the ID of the sector in the query otherwise you might have lines to one sector crossing bearing polylines of other sectors.

Here's an image illustrating my idea
[image]

Comment: sure, I get your approach. I just want to make it as dynamic as possible. For example, I have 1000 sites and Im planning 10 new ones within these 1000. How can I locate the sectors of existing sites at 1 km away from the 10 new sites? Like, how would i be able to create those polyline that you mentioned will eventually cross the point/new site (with a lat lon) ?

Comment: @Karl, can you try sharing an image illustrating what you are trying to do? There has been similar questions here about creating sectors using MapBasic. I'm sure some of these might give you an idea of how to create the polyline, I was mentioning. Let me try to find some answers for you

Comment: I have added a link to an answer and also an illustration of my suggestion

Comment: I shared with you an illustration just adding 3 sectors (Random 33 degree beamwidth). So, what i am trying to do is to identify which of the 3 sectors point to the "BearingPolyline" for example. Is there a way to program it in MapBasic? 

If i do it with "lines crossing bearings" from potential sites to existing one, then with the case of the top right potential site, it doesnt satisfy the case; however, it also interferes with the traffic absorbed by the sector of the existing site.. So i still want to include it... I hope with the explanation, I clarified and not confused you further

Comment: From your drawing only the two sites would be of interest, right? The one in the top right corner doesn't meet the criteria so that one can be removed. Or are you saying that there are other criterias, too?

Comment: you are right; however, if I want to include the one in the top right because it also serves the traffic falling in the area of the bearing of the existing site.. How will I be able to achieve that?